# Two-Way iBeacon with 2 iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I have been trying to setup '**Two-Way iBeacon Communication**' between two iOS devices. I tried to use [This Technique on PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/smart-ibeacon-communication-in-the-swift-programming-language/), and I guess I have managed to start the emitter for transmitting. However, both phones do not match as showed in this [video](https://vimeo.com/99798858).

As I have lack of experience and this guide is not very clear for me, please take a look in my code. There is no error I am receiving and projects work fine on both iPhones and I can see Emitter is transmitting correctly, however they do not match.

*For both emitter and receiver, I have imported CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth Frameworks and I have added 'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' and 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription' in info.plist by clicking the '+' (not coded in from Source Code).*

**Emitter Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
var major = 9
var minor = 6
let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: "0CF052C2-97CA-407C-84F8-B62AAC4E9020")
var peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
var advertisedData = NSDictionary()   
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 9, minor: 6, identifier: "com.yourcampany.example")
    self.advertisedData = region.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(nil)
    self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    switch peripheral.state {
    case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisedData)
        self.powerON.text = "Power ON"
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**Receiver Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

 var region = CLBeaconRegion()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: "0CF052C2-97CA-407C-84F8-B62AAC4E9020")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "com.yourcampany.example")
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(self.region)
 }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: NSArray!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    var beacon = beacons.lastObject as CLBeacon
    switch beacon.proximity {
    case CLProximity.Immediate:
       self.label.text = "Immediate"
    case CLProximity.Near:
        self.label.text = "Near"
    default:
       self.label.text = "AAA"
    }
}
```

The label on my Main.storyboard is not setting to any of the values "Immediate","Near" or "AAA".

Also, what is the most logical way if I want to transfer a string (made of 5-6 characters). I have read it is not possible to send huge block of data but how about a string of a few characters? *[maybe using **CentralManager** and **PeripheralManager**]*

Comment: Do you get prompted for location usage on the receiver?  If not, you may not have permission set up properly.

Comment: You don't seem to have called `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:`

Comment: @davidyoung: By saying prompted, do you mean the console? I don't get anything prompted at the console for receiver (whereas, I do in console for emitter). 
Also, I am pretty sure emitter is working fine because when bluetooth is closed, i have a text label that says loading but when i turn the bluetooth on, it says "power on".

@Paulw11: Where should i put the `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` ? I am very confused.

Comment: Also, with regard to your final question - if you want to transfer data, iBeacon isn't the way - you will need to operate as a CoreBluetooth peripheral/central or look into the mutineer connectivity framework

Comment: Can I use as 'if iBeacons are connected, send data using multineer connectivity framework '? Or this is not logical way? What I want to do is _sharing phone ids when two iphones are as close as couple of centimeters_.

Comment: It sounds like you want CoreBluetooth where a phone will advertise an ID via a CBPeripheral and listen for these peripherals using a CBCentral.  iBeacon doesn't "connect", it simply broadcasts an ID & two numbers (major and minor)

Comment: @Paul11 Exactly. But if I am going to use an && statement (i.e. if iBeacon range is medium, send string using CBPeripheral and receive using CBCentral).  I need to combine both iBeacon and CBPeripheral+CBCentral. Is that right? (By the way, thanks so much for your responses)

Comment: The difficulty you will have with this approach is if you have more than two devices in range - you can't correlate the iBeacon id with the CBPeripheral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called `self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.region)`.  Without this call you won't get callbacks to the `didRangeBeacons` delegate method.  You have called `self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(self.region)` but this will result in calls to your `didEnterRegion` & `didExitRegion` delegate methods.

So you should have -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "com.yourcampany.example")
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.region)
 }
```

Comment: I have changed the line to `self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.region)` as you said and added `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),` as _davidyoung_ said but still nothing changed. Instead when I added `self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.region)`, I started getting _fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_

Comment: You need to see which value was nil and on what line.

Comment: It doesn't happen in a line. It just gets prompted in the console 'when I press exit the simulator after successfully running it' and also 'when mounting on phone is successful'.

Comment: I worked for a second and then again, I started getting same fatal error message. http://i.imgur.com/hDMZ2tC.png http://i.imgur.com/X1MMVPx.png

Comment: Try clicking on the blue thread spool and see if you can work out where it is  crashing from the stack trace.  Something is nil that you haven't checked for.

Comment: Edit: I think the problem for the receiver phone is, when there is an emitter in the area, it works fine and detects the emitter. However, if I close the app on the emitter side, the receiver app kicks me out as soon as it gets opened. Any idea?

Comment: Something is nil in that case - you need to debug it to work out why.  I don't know about Swift - its exception handling seems a bit flakey, but in Objective C I would set an exception breakpoint to see where the problem was

Comment: I think the failed part is:  `var beacon = beacons.lastObject as CLBeacon`. http://i.imgur.com/lVJ8UPB.png . What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the array is empty.  You should test the `count` of the array in that delegate method and do nothing if it is empty

Comment: Yes, this is how I managed to sort out. (i.e. If beacons.count > 0)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do for sure is change your callback code to manipulate the UI on the main thread.  You must wrap your UI changes like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    switch beacon.proximity {
    case CLProximity.Immediate:
       self.label.text = "Immediate"
    case CLProximity.Near:
        self.label.text = "Near"
    default:
       self.label.text = "AAA"
    }
});
```

Comment: I have just `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` at the top of the closure `func locationManager()` right under `var beacon` exactly as you showed. But unfortunately, nothing has changed.